# Get browser's active MediaSession data via extension API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mediasession

Using a Chrome extension, I'd like to log the metadata from media played in the browser from pages that use the [MediaSession API](https://w3c.github.io/mediasession/).

Is it possible to get the current [active MediaSession](https://w3c.github.io/mediasession/#media-session-routing)?  If not, is it possible to get the MediaSession for a particular tab/window?  (I suppose if I could get that far, I could emulate Chrome's behavior in determining which should be 'active'.)

As far as I can tell, the only way would be to inject code into every page, all the time.  I'm quite open to better methods, if this is exposed via an extension API somewhere!

Comment: Without injecting, highly unlikely, especially for something that's still a draft.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I'll quite happily accept a "no" answer.  Someone might as well get the bounty.  :-)

Comment: you can try using tabCapture permission for access

Comment: @Nithur I did not, unfortunately.  Please post an answer if you find one!