# Reatime data capture from music streaming services

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, progressive-web-apps, spotify, audio-streaming, soundcloud

Is it a possibility, in realtime capture the data of what a user is currently listening to, the playlists they like/follow/created?

For instance, **user A** is listening to a song on Spotify and **User N** is also listening to a song the same song on the same platform. Now, is there a chance to capture the real-time data of what users are listening to, and build a community to match the users?

Comment: yes it is. Are you looking for the community to build a tech chart for you? What have you done yet, where are you struggling?

Comment: You'll need to make a browser extension and write code for each site you want to monitor.  Also, related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/64416177/362536